# (SQL) Get comma separated specific value total count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the total number of occurrences by separate server ID like below :

```
-----------------------------
logID               serversID
-------------------------------
1                   50,51,51,50
2                   51,52
3                   50,50
```

I want a result like this:

```
ServerID     Count
------------ --------------- 
50           4
51           3
52           1
```

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Specify your server version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your data model!  A string is the wrong way to store multiple values.  A string is the wrong way to store numbers.  The correct way to represent this data is to use a second table, with one row per `logid` and `serverid`.

If you are stuck with this data model and you don't have a reference table for servers, you can split the values . . . painfully:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(t.serversid, ',', n.n), ',', -1) as server, count(*)
from (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3 union all
      . . .   -- as many as the biggest list
     ) n join
     t
     on t.servers like concat(repeat('%,', n.n - 1), '%')
group by server;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb45dee4a164b0e02eab49a17015ee5f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Fixing the data model is probably less painful than resorting to SQL olympics +1.